# Combining enum values in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Why is this code ([ideone](http://ideone.com/GwevB5)) not allowed? What would be the workaround?

```
enum testEnum { e1, e2 };
testEnum te = e1 | e2;
```

*error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'main()::testEnum'*

Comment: The problem is essentially the same as `testEnum te = 1;`, as hinted by the error.

Comment: If you want it to *compile*, you need `testEnum te = static_cast<testEnum>(e1 | e2);` But you should explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Which member of `testEnum` is represented by the expression `e1 | e2`?